# Nested SQL select query and writing it with Rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

What I have is a Skus model/table that has several columns that represent categories. There are also three columns that are used to describe a version number in major, minor, micro format.

I would like to select the highest version of each Sku based on three of the Sku categories.

Initially I tried using MAX and 'group', but that did not work well with the three version number columns(0 0 5 is considered bigger than 0 1 0). So I resorted to using 'order by' over the three version columns then performing a 'select' with 'group by' which gives the result I want:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT *
  FROM skus
  WHERE category1_id = 3
  ORDER BY ver_major, ver_minor, ver_micro
) 
GROUP BY category2_id, category3_id, category4_id
```

What I wondered is, is this particularly inefficient (because of the nested select or otherwise)?

And most importantly, how would I write this (or a better) query using Rails ActiveRecord?

Thanks for any help

Comment: It didn't resolve your problem, but does your table have indexes on ver_major, ver_minor, ver_micro, category2_id, category3_id and category4_id ? It will help your database engine to compute ORDER BY and GROUP BY.

Comment: This also wont resolve your problem, but it's a good idea to get into the habit of avoiding "SELECT *" unless you need the data from every column. Select only the columns you need, your query time will be much smaller.

Comment: Thanks for both replies. I do have indexes on the categories. I also would not use * for the SELECT but was simplifying the problem. My main issue is how to represent something like this using Rails ActiveRecord methods.

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of database design, it's never a good idea to put category ids into skus table.

A sku may have many categories, and a category may have many skus. You need a join table with two fields(sku_id and category_id) to store the relationship.

The modelling in Rails would look like

```
class Sku < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :skus
end
```

Ref: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The relationship is actually that each SKU has one ID of each of the categories. Category is maybe a bad word, property might be better; property_thing1_id, property_thing2_id etc